# Flutter on Visual Studio Code does not reload on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I write Flutter code on Visual Studio Code with Flutter extension.
Since several days ago, auto hot reloading not working as before.
There's no message on debug console window even if I run 'Hot Reload' or 'Hot Restart' command from command pallet.

I've tried to restart my Mac and reinstall VS extension but no changes.
What's wrong or what should check for?

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.3.9-pre.41, on Mac OS X 10.14.2 18C54, locale en-KR)
    • Flutter version 1.3.9-pre.41 at /Users/hyoon/dev/tools/flutter
    • Framework revision 1fa1e1a17c (3 hours ago), 2019-03-09 04:29:28 -0500
    • Engine revision a63ff46327
    • Dart version 2.2.1 (build 2.2.1-dev.1.0 2fb6cd9f5f)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/hyoon/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/hyoon/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    • ios-deploy 2.0.0
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 29.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.32.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.24.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 5s • DC0A93F9-3A3A-4CEA-92AF-914F10C907B8 • ios • iOS 12.1 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've downgraded to 1.31 and it works now.